# how to use strotime to update mysql unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, unix

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$insert = "INSERT INTO sql(name, time, time_end) VALUES ('".$name."', '". strtotime('now')."', '". strtotime('+2 days')."') ;";
    mysqli_query($conn, $insert);
```

Insert query to process data from a form, and displaying time in PST

```
dispay.php

name             started at                    ending at 

test            March 7, 2019, 3:41 pm        March 10, 2019, 3:41 pm

stack           March 8, 2019, 6:53 am        March 9, 2019, 6:53 pm
```

So I've radiobuttons in the form to pick the duration of hours to add and then submit..
Added 72hrs to test and 24 hours to stack

If I have to update the time_end, I don't know how exactly to use strtotime in update query, so I tried added seconds directly to it using this query

```
$update = "UPDATE table SET
    time_end = time_end + 252900
    where name = 'test' ;";
    mysqli_query($conn, $update);
```

Then it would display

```
dispay.php

name             started at                    ending at 

test            March 7, 2019, 3:41 pm        March 13, 2019, 4:41 pm

stack           March 8, 2019, 6:53 am        March 9, 2019, 6:53 pm
```

The problem is it adds an extra hour when I use update query in this way and not while I use the insert one. Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't display the time accurately? Give us some examples. What are your expectations, what values do you get. How is the DB relevant for this? If you are storing integers, then DB schema should be irrelevant. How do you convert the timestamp to PST?

Comment: Explained in edit @Dharman

Comment: This is because California will switch to DST on Sunday, 10 March at 02:00

Comment: So if the data from my insert query works fine in PST, is there no way to do the same with update query?

Comment: Stop thinking about SQL, this has nothing to do with SQL!. This is a logical fault in your thinking. Give me few minutes I will try to explain it to you.

Comment: `time_end = time_end + INTERVAL 2 DAY`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mysqli_` prepared statements to avoid sql injection vulnerabilities.

But here is the `UPDATE` query that should work;

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4AH8mJyogLMeruseABPhiD/0

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO sql(name, time, time_end) 
           VALUES ( ? , NOW() , NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY)";

$update = "UPDATE sql SET
                  time_end = time_end + INTERVAL 2 DAY
           WHERRE name = ? ";
```

You can use this query for [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) this way:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $insert); 
/* bind parameters for markers */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $name);
/* execute query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL INTERVAL will work on integers. You would need to cast it to native data and then back again to int.

Comment: @Dharman do you have table schema? how do you know type? I would expect that to be datetime not integer

Comment: Yeah, this update query doesn't work either. I've time_end set at INT type, should I change to something else to work?

Comment: Yes, OP posted in the original question that the fields are integers. He has since removed that remark.

Comment: @influx Alex has a point. While he hasn't explained your problem like I did, he is right that you should store the time and date in MySQL native formats. Then you can use the built-in SQL functions to perform such operations easily.

Comment: @influx it should be datetime type

Comment: nvm, both work. Can you tell me how can you also tell how to add hours to it instead of just days-wise? @Alex

Answer (score 1):

Time can be counted almost perfectly in consecutive seconds. i.e. 1,2,3,4 seconds have passed and so on.
This is exactly what a unix timestamp is; it is a number of seconds passed since a specific point in time, which is the UNIX epoch. Because this is a number of seconds passed it can be expressed as an integer.
However our calendars and clocks are not counting the time consecutively in a straight line. Time and dates are very complicated and relative concepts. At one moment it could be 1.59am and literally the next second it will be 3.00am. Another six months after that, you relive the same hour twice.
This is illustrated by my [example in PHP over here](https://ideone.com/3O0W2s).

In your example you are skipping an hour on the clock, but your count of seconds didn't account for this difference. One simple way of doing this could be as follows:

```
$start = 1552211999;
$dt = new DateTime('@'.$start);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$dt->modify('+1 day');
```

[Try it online at Ideone](https://ideone.com/IFkn1C)